# Fixed Double Headers, Scrollable Content (Mobile App)

Tags: css, html, blackberry-webworks

I have problem design the layout for a mobile app using WebWorks. The layout of the page is:

```
----------------Title Header (div#title)-----------------
----------------Tabs Header(div#tabs)--------------------
-----------       content  (div#content)  ----------------
```

The markup:

```
<body>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="title">Some title</div>
    <div id="tabs">Some navigation tabs</div>
    <div id="content>
      <!--- some contents that could be in contain in div or table populated from       
      database-->
    </div> 
  </div>
```

div#title and div#tabs are the fixed headers. div#content is meant to be scrollable vertically without overlapping div#title and div#tabs and also to scroll horizontally yet div#title and div#tabs must not move or go out of sight when scrolling horizontally.

I have tried setting positon: fixed to div#title and div#tabs but when trying to scroll the in BlackBerry phone there are some lagging issues whereby div#title and div#tabs takes a long time to refresh and display itself.

If position: fixed cannot be used, is there anyone to fixed the headers yet make the content scrollable without overlapping or stretching the layout?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've always dealt with the scrolling like this:

`body {
  position: fixed;
}`

`#title, #tabs {
  position: fixed;
}`

`#content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; // for bb10
}`

Note if you're targeting BlackBerry 10, -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;, will allow you to make use of the inertial scrolling effect.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have changed the #content overflow-y: scroll to overflow: auto, then when I try to scroll to right the top headers are lagging when scrolling and they take time to load.